# Pointcloud background subtraction

Tags: 3d, image-segmentation, point-clouds, open3d, pytorch3d

Let say I have two pointcloud, one just the plane and another object placed on a plane. I want to perform background removal from the second pointcloud. Is there a way to perform this?

**Note** - I am aware of performing this on rgb image. I am curious about if there something exists for 3d pointcloud.

Comment: Hi. I would try to perform ICP to align the two point clouds, then remove the points that matched (supposedly part of the plane) and keep the points that didn't match (supposedly part of the other object).

Comment: @Stef I understand the registration process, I can do it. But how would you implement removal of points. Can you provide an example using two ply files.